# Aptana spell checking

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana, spell-checking

I'm currently using Aptana as an Eclipse plugin and I noticed that when I make a typo in my comments (PHP) that it underlines it with a squiggly line. However, Aptana seems to be smart enough to know that I made a type but I can't find any option to let it make the spelling correction for me (like a right click on the word and to be presented with a number of options).

Is this something I need to enable explicitly to be able to do this or am I just overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can press <kbd>ctrl-1</kbd> to get a list of potential corrections.

[image: spelling corrections screenshot]
<sub>(source: [javalobby.org](http://www.javalobby.org/images/postings/rj/eclipse_spelling/3.jpg))</sub>

You can also use auto-complete to provide suggestions as you type by pressing <kbd>ctrl-space</kbd>

[image: auto-complete screenshot]
<sub>(source: [javalobby.org](http://www.javalobby.org/images/postings/rj/eclipse_spelling/4.jpg))</sub>